# How do i run php file in my heroku static app

Tags: php, heroku

I have added php file into my static app using resources directory and I used the following directory structure to deploy my app on heroku.

```
-Static
  -public
    -css (all css files)
    -js (all js files)
    -images(all images)
    -resources (pdfs,test.php)
    -index.html
  -config.ru
  -Gemfile
  -Gemfile.lock
  -Readme.md
```

Now, i want to run the php file(test.php) on submitting the form.But it is not executing on heroku.Can any one help me to describe the steps for running the php file.

Comment: Also, please consider [formatting your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for readability.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: Rename your index.html in e.g. home.html. Create a index.php and link to your home.html.

Credits: [This site](http://www.lemiffe.com/how-to-deploy-a-static-page-to-heroku-the-easy-way/)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

When running PHP Scripts on Heroku now don't use the PHP path.  Just use "php".

```
heroku run php --version

sudo heroku run php path/to/file.php
```

( may not need to use sudo - taken from the example above - I don't use sudo )